# Is it possible to allow an iframe to resizeTo/By moveTo/By?

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, parent, postmessage

Is it possible to configure the parent of an iframe so that it allows the iframe to resizeTo and similar functions (moveTo) ?

Or do I need to manually pass message to the parent ?

iframe

```
window.resizeTo = function(w,h){
 parent.postMessage({
  "command":"window_resizeTo",
  "data":{width:w,height:h}
 }, "*")
}
```

parent

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
 var message = event.data;
 var command = message.command;
 var properties = message.data;

 switch(command)
 {
    case "window_resizeTo":
        $(#iframe").setAttribute("style", `width:${properties.width}px;height:${properties.height}px`)
        break;
    // and so on for every function I wish to proxy
 }
}
```

EDIT:
iframe and parent are of the same origin.
I know I could use window.parent from inside the iframe (and then resizing the iframe will be easy).
My question was more about iframe options that will allow autobinding rather than having to do it myself.

EDIT2
This probably does not exist. Because use case will be too narrow. Even if parent is ok with letting iframe resize themselves, parent would probably want to limit the area and/or add an offset.

ANSWER is :
There's already window.resizeTo and alike functions in the iframe but (because of abuse) they probably do nothing.
If you want to resize/move the iframe in the context of a parent, you'll have to do the "binding" yourself.
There's no direct binding : you'll have to translate resize functions in functions that change offset/width of the iframe. If the iframe and parent are of the same origin you could manipulate the parent (and so the iframe) from the parent itself. I don't recommend this.
The better option is probably sending message to the parent.

Comment: Does the IFrame follow the same origin policy?

Comment: Yes it does. Description changed to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IFrame-Content is loaded from a different origin, you have to use the postMessage-Event to give the IFrame the opportunity of changing his size. Take a look at [Definition of an origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin) at MDN.

If the IFrame-Content follows the same origin policy, you can access the `window.parent.document` from within the iframe and modify the node at the parent directly.

The node at the parent document could be found using:

```js
// script at the iframe document
try {
  const node = [...window.parent.document.querySelectorAll("iframe")]
     .find(iframe => {
       try { // avoid errors from inaccessible iframes
         return iframe.contentWindow == window
       } catch (e) {}
     });
  if (node) {
    node.setAttribute("style", "...");
  }
} catch(e) {
  // unable to access parent
}
```

Comment: After thinking about it, my question does not make much sense. Anyway the two method I can think of to alter the iframe properties are yours (iframe manipulating its parent) and mine (iframe sends message to its parent). So I flagged your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example, work for me, regards.

```
<script type="application/javascript">    

    function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {

        iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
        iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
   }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
            var iFrame = document.getElementById( 'iFrame1' );
            resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );

            // or, to resize all iframes:
            var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
            for( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            resizeIFrameToFitContent( iframes[i] );
       }
    });

</script>

<iframe src="usagelogs/default.aspx" id="iFrame1"></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68796085/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you Roddmason for your answer. I'm not 100% sure the "DOMContentLoaded" event applies to the domcontent of the iframe too. Your code (If I understand it well) is more about resizing one(all) iframes to their real size. This is nice. But in my case the resize event of the iframe can occur at any time. I think it's better to let the iframe signal its parent when it wants to be resized.

Comment: @v1nce `DOMContentLoaded` applies only to the current window, not iframes, but `<iframe onload>` is triggered every time the iframe has changed it's location, without telling you anything else like the uri it was changed to. You can check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6hm3qe/